# Identifying whether a laptop has HDMI 2.0 or 1.4

Tags: hdmi

Sorry if this is considered off-topic - not sure where else to ask this. I have a ASUS ROG GL552VW laptop and am trying to figure out whether the HDMI port on it supports HDMI 2.0. I wish to use it to output 4k content onto a TV. However, after reading the manual, and a few hours of searching online I simply cannot find this information. I also struggled to find it for other laptops too. Is there some driver I can look for on my laptop which would tell me if it does indeed support HDMI 2.0? Or something else?

TL;DR Does this laptop "ASUS ROG GL552VW" support HDMI 2.0?

Comment: This is likely more ontopic on Super User. Check their site tour to make sure though.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Most OSs have tools that will allow you to more precisely list what devices (such as video cards/outputs) are installed and what their capabilities are.

Comment: @GarethPulham Windows 10 - also in every list I could find HDMI is just listed as "HDMI" with no more information

Comment: Apparently there's no way to probe this information, but this answer is interesting https://askubuntu.com/questions/588018/how-to-find-out-the-hdmi-version-supported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I voted for a move to superuser.com since it might be better for this question. However... I think I can answer as well.

Your laptop appears to have a Nvidia GTX960M which apparently does not support HDMI 2.0: https://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GTX-960M.138006.0.html
You'll be able to run a 4k TV but only at 30 Hz, which is enough for most movies but can be limiting for some.

Comment: Okay thanks I hadn't heard of superuser before, so I'll be sure to look at that. Also thanks for the answer - if you don't mind me asking; does the fact that the GPU doesn't support HDMI 2.0 necessarily mean that the computer doesn't support HDMI 2.0? That is to say, if I upgraded the GPU, would it then support HDMI 2.0? (forgive me if this doesn't make sense as I have little understanding as to how HDMI 2.0 works).

Comment: Yes, that's the result unfortunately. If your GPU can't handle it the computer can't handle it. Unfortunately I doubt you can replace the graphics card in your laptop.

Comment: @mrnovice I have the same laptop. The integrated Intel HD 530 should be able to support 4K @ 60 Hz. However, the hybrid GTX 960M probably limited it (?). I never managed to get 4K @ 60 Hz. But I can add a custom resolution of 2560x1440 @ 60 Hz and 2848x1600 @ 60 Hz using a 18 Gbps HDMI cable, so currently that's good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

from Quora: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-know-which-version-of-the-HDMI-port-I-have-on-my-laptop?share=1

"If you have any Intel Core-based laptop up to the 9th gen, you’ll be limited to HDMI 1.4a while the 10th gen Ice lake series support HDMI 2.0b. For AMD Ryzen APUs, they’re capped to HDMI 2.0b.

This is also applicable to laptops with dedicated graphics as all display output is still handled by the iGPU."